# How can i update the midpoint in my code?

Tags: java, binary-search

```
while(looper)
    {
    char higher = 'h';
    char lower = 'l';
    guess = getMidpoint(min,max);
    char respons = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);

    if(respons == 'c'){
        looper = false;

    }
    else if(respons == higher)
     {  
        min = min + 1;
        getMidpoint(min,max);
     }
    else if(respons == lower)
     {
        max = min - 1;
        getMidpoint(min,max);           
     }

    }
public static int getMidpoint(int low, int high)
{
    int midpoint;
    midpoint = (high + low) / 2;
    return midpoint;        
}
```

So basically this is a guessing game that uses binary search, and the getMidpoint method gets the mid of the two numbers, min is 1 and max is 100. h stands for high and l stands for lower and c stands for correct. I have everything correct but the guess keeps coming out weird, like it give me random numbers. How can i update the max and min so it comes out correct? Hopefully i worded this right.

Comment: Please show the implementation of `getMidpoint()`.

Comment: `max = min - 1`? Also you call `getMidpoint` without saving the return value and then again saving it.

Comment: The code you have shown so far does not make any sense. You do not show much effort.

Comment: it's okay the other guy helped solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if(respons == higher)
 {  
    min = min + 1;
    getMidpoint(min,max);
 }
else if(respons == lower)
 {
    max = min - 1;
    getMidpoint(min,max);           
 }
```

This part is strange. If the guess should be *higher*, you should do `min = midpoint + 1` instead of only increasing `min` by 1. And when it should be *lower*, you should do `max = midpoint - 1`.

You haven't shown the implementation of `getMidpoint()`, so I'm not sure whether `guess` could be used as the new `min`/`max` or not.

Comment: 'code'public static int getMidpoint(int low, int high)
 {
  int midpoint;
  midpoint = (high + low) / 2;
  return midpoint;  
 }'code'

Comment: Then you should do `min = guess + 1` or `max = guess - 1`.

Comment: omg Thank you!! i was stuck on this for two days. It's finally working the way it's supposed to.